# Send GPS coords when the app is minimized (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, gps, real-time, push-notification

I want to build an app that is checking the current user GPS coords and send it to the server when the server asks for it.
Is it possible at all to do this when the app is minimized?

How can I implement a service like this? It should be real-time:

The server asks for users locations --> The clients are sending their current location --> The server processing their location --> The server is sending to X of them a notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10

Comment: But if I'll check for location in background, it'll drain the client's iPhone and it won't be as real-time as it should be. I thought about implementing a system that checks when the server *is asking* for their location, but I don't know where I should start coding it.

Comment: You are right, although there is an option to only receive significant location updates (not sure what is defined as significant, maybe a few miles difference?) that decreases battery consumption drastically. Looks like this guy concluded that it is accurate to 500 meters. http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/#more-480

Comment: To comment on checking if the server is asking for their location... iOS doesn't have a background service for networking threads like that, unless you could mask it as a VOIP app, which would probably get rejected from the AppStore.

Comment: Okay, and let's say I wrote some code to implement the server request-client responds. Is it possible to check and send gps coords at background? Or even run some code in the background?